# Want to get a part of a image

Tags: python, image, pygame

I am making google's t-rex runner game. So I got a .png file which contains all the fonts, picuters of the t-rex, etc. So I am now having problem in getting a part of the image. Here is the image:

[image: This is the image]

Is there anyway in which I can get a part of the image. I am using python, pygame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know what a [Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) and [Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) is, here is a way to do it:

```
    def image_at(png, rectangle): # rectangle would be the section you want in the png
        rect = pygame.Rect(rectangle)
        image = pygame.Surface(rect.size)
        image.blit(png, (0, 0), rect)
        return image
```

(inspired by https://www.pygame.org/wiki/Spritesheet which could be exactly what you were looking for)

Basically you create a surface with the dimensions of your desired section of the png, they you draw (blit) the whole png on your created surface, and that will show only the part you selected throught your rectangle.

Comment: I want to store that part of the image in a variable any idea how?

Comment: I found my answer in the link

Comment: you can just call your function like this for example: `sprite = image_at(png, rectangle)` then use `sprite` like any other surface (btw i did an oopsie in my response remove the self argument or recopy the answer)

Comment: In your function, what is the format for ```rectangle```?? Am I supposed to put coordinates or what?

Comment: yes use these coordinates (top, left, width, height)

Comment: got it, is this correct (0, 0, width, hieght)?

Comment: It is correct yes (assuming width and height are defined before ofc)